# How to filter rows from Julia Array based on value of value in specified column?

Tags: filter, julia

I have data like this in a text file:

```
CLASS     col2    col3    ...
1         ...     ...     ...
1         ...     ...     ...
2         ...     ...     ...
2         ...     ...     ...
2         ...     ...     ...
```

I load them using the following code:

```
data = readdlm("file.txt")[2:end, :] # without header line
```

And now I would like to get array with rows only from class 1.

(Data could be loaded using some other function if it would help.)

Comment: You might find [the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/DataFrames) useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logical indexing is the straight-forward way to do filtering on an array:

```
data[data[:,1] .== 1, :]
```

If, though, you read your file in as a data frame, you'll have more options available to you, and it'll keep track of your headers:

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> df = readtable("file.txt", separator=' ')
5×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ CLASS │ col2  │ col3  │ _     │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 2   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 3   │ 2     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 4   │ 2     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 5   │ 2     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │

julia> df[df[:CLASS] .== 1, :] # Refer to the column by its header name
2×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ CLASS │ col2  │ col3  │ _     │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 2   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
```

There are even more tools available with the [DataFramesMeta package](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl) that aim to make this simpler (and other packages actively under development).  You can use its `@where` macro to do SQL-style filtering:

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta
julia> @where(df, :CLASS .== 1)
2×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ CLASS │ col2  │ col3  │ _     │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
│ 2   │ 1     │ "..." │ "..." │ "..." │
```

Comment: For me `df[df[:CLASS] .== 1, :]` gave an error, but `df[df[!, :CLASS] .== 1, :]` worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
data[find(x -> a[x,1] == 1, 1:size(data)[1]),:]
```

Comment: No need to make it so convoluted. Just `data[data[:,1] .== 1, :]` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh jesus I was trying to do that for so long,   forgot to do the : at the end

Comment: @MattB. You could write it as a separate answer. ;)

Comment: @Luke done. I figured it could be a simple edit for `@isebarn`, but I've added a few more options in my answer.

Comment: I thought it was "stealing" to edit my response to your answer